# Loop numbers through Dropdown but getting number instead of letters

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

What I'm trying to do is put a letters in the value of each dropdown, depending on dropdown.
But I'm getting numbers instead of letters. And how to end the loop when it reach letter Z?

I'm getting 1 instead of A and 2 instead of B and so on. And how to get all characters except for the last in value. I used substring

**Table Structure**

```
id  |  maincode | category  
1   |  BAS-01   |  Supplies
2   |  BAS-02   |  IT Equipment
3   |  BAS-03   |  Office Equipment

<select name="maincode" id="maincode" onchange="GetChangedValue(this.value);">
<option value=""></option>
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "data");
$result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY id");

while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {

    if (empty($result2)) {
        $data = 'A';
    } else {
        $data++;
    }
    //echo $data; //A ++
    echo "<option value='".$row['maincode'].$data."'>".$row['category']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<script>
$('[name="maincode"]').change(function() {
   $('[name="item"]').val($(this).val()substring(0,5));
});
</script>
<input type="" name="item" id="item" value="">
```

Comment: can you post the sample data you fetch from db 
      SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY id

Comment: `$ok` is being used where?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Nothing, sorry I will erase that.

Comment: if `$row['maincode'].$data` is the number and `$row['category']` the letter, you could use `$row['category']` for the option value as well

Comment: @Dagon I tried that. But It display number also

Comment: what's the actual html output look like

Comment: @Dagon I updated my question and put my table Structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another `$data = 'A';` outside of while loop.

```
$data = 'A';
while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {

    if (empty($result2)) {
        $data = 'A';
    } else {
        $data++;
    }
    //echo $data; //A ++
    echo "<option value='".$row['maincode'].$data."'>".$row['category']."</option>";
}
```